# How to flag a user with an offensive username?

Tags: discussion, trolling, user-accounts, behaviour

Or resident troll seems to be moving to more offensive behaviour:

Link now removed as the user seems to have been removed and the URL contained the offending language.

Answer (score 8):

Flag any of their content with a custom "requires moderator attention" flag.

If they don't have any content, flag any of your own with the same. Be as descriptive as possible. Moderators can see the full text of your flag, so flagging one of your own posts with a custom flag is the best way to flag something which has no other anchor points to flag.

A validated custom flag on one of your posts has no negative repercussions for you in itself, it does not by itself count against you in any way.

Answer (score 2):

You could use the "in need of moderator intervention" text box next to any of their content to note that the username is offensive. That might do.

Comment: They don’t have content that’s why he’s asking.

Comment: Unfortunately, I missed my opportunity as the question they did pretty has been deleted

Comment: Or just flag ***anything*** at all (including this post, for example) with an "in need of a moderator" comment. They'll read it and then act accordingly.